# Location spoofing in an HTTP Web Request

Tags: http, web, http-headers

When trying to access [tripadvisor.com](https://tripadvisor.com), TripAdvisor redirects you to the localized version of the website. In my case, it redirects to tripadvisor.com.ph since I am in the Philippines.

In sending raw HTTP web requests using curl or some tool, how does one spoof the current location to a different location? Is it possible to do this without spoofing the IP address?

Comment: It seems that tripadvisor use ip geolocation in conjunction with Accept-Language header. Cause with default browser settings I get redircted to tripadvisor.ru but if I change Accept-Language in browser to ph then www.tripadvisor.com don't redirect but currency in interface is russian ruble.

Comment: @Ilya Then we have no choice but to use a VPN, right?

Comment: It seems that ip masking is the only way to do this